# Symfony2: Login via user or IP

Tags: authentication, symfony

Is it possible to authenticate via username or IP in Symfony2? 
I know that it's possible to login with username and password or by IP address, but is it also possible to authenticate when I come from a specfic IP address automatically and if not then via username and password?

***Example:***

If I come from 10.1.1.1 I want to get the ADMIN_ROLE

If I come from a different IP I have to login via username and password

Here comes my security.yml

```
        secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /login
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN  }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 10.1.1.1 }
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but not secure. You can do chained authentication providers (firewall section in the security.yml)

In your case you will need to implement a custom one for the IP authentication method. You can find a documentation writing a custom authentication provider in the Symfony cookbook( want: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html)

You will have to chain your custom provider and the Symfony2 form auth provider.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible in Symfony. It's quite a security hole as IP addresses can be faked. That's why I would recommend you to search another login method.

If you want more information about this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing

Instead of authorizing by IP, why not provide a certificate that could be used to authenticate the user? That way the incoming request needs some piece of knowledge (the certificate) that is not publicly available?

Comment: Why is it so insecure, as attackers who faked the IP address won't get any response?